# How to edit this HTML & CSS code to achieve those requirements?

Tags: html, css

I need to move all the below part starting "Some of my favorite places:
My Chair
The Couch
The car maybe!
Make sure to visit my facebook page."

to be reinserted beside the image with the margin 30 px 
I tried a lot but every time I do that, the result, unfortunately, becomes distorted!

```
<h1>Misho the Boss</h1>
<p>Hi, I'm a cat. Meow!</p> 
<img src="Misho.jpg">
<h3>Some of my favorite places:</h3>
<ul>
  <li>My Chair</li>
  <li>The Couch</li>
  <li>The Car Maybe!</li>
</ul>
<p>Make sure to visit my <a href="http:\\www.facebook.com">facebook</a> page.</p>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: lavenderblush;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Berkshire Swash;
}

p, li, h3 {
    font-family: Gloria Hallelujah;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the sections within divs, then assign a percentage width to each of them. That way you can adjust the percentage as you see fit.

```css
body {
    background: lavenderblush;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Berkshire Swash;
}

p, li, h3 {
    font-family: Gloria Hallelujah;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.left, .right { width: 50%; display: inline-block; }

.left {
float: left;
}
```

```html
<h1>Misho the Boss</h1>

<div class="left">
<p>Hi, I'm a cat. Meow!</p> 
<img src="Misho.jpg">
</div>
<div class="right">
<h3>Some of my favorite places:</h3>
<ul>
  <li>My Chair</li>
  <li>The Couch</li>
  <li>The Car Maybe!</li>
</ul>
<p>Make sure to visit my <a href="http:\\www.facebook.com">facebook</a> page.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use divs to make two columns and add margin to img for spacing like below:

```css
body {
background: lavenderblush;
}

h1 {
font-family: Berkshire Swash;
}

p, li, h3 {
font-family: Gloria Hallelujah;
}

h3 {
font-size: 20px;
}
.first-half, .second-half {width:50%;display:inline-block;}
.first-half {float:left;}
.space {margin-right:30px;}
```

```html
 <div class="first-half">
 <h1>Misho the Boss</h1>
 <p>Hi, I'm a cat. Meow!</p> 
 <img src="Misho.jpg" class="space">
 </div>
 <div class="second-half">
 <h3>Some of my favorite places:</h3>
 <ul>
 <li>My Chair</li>
 <li>The Couch</li>
 <li>The Car Maybe!</li>
 </ul>
 <p>Make sure to visit my <a href="http:\\www.facebook.com">facebook</a> page.</p> 
 </div>
```